# Dictionary enumeration order

Tags: c#, .net

Documentation says `Dictionary` keys order is unspecified. I guess it means the first added element may be not first during enumeration. But does `Dictionary` guarantee order to be the same each time I enumerate it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, currently it does return items in the same order (assuming that you don't trigger a resize of the hashtable in the meantime).

**No, you should not depend on it**.

Generally speaking, unless there is an explicit guarantee that the order remains the same, then you cannot assume *anything*. And such a guarantee most certainly [is not given](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

If you are interested in the details for academic purposes, see [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2011/09/16/103362.aspx) excellent blog post.